# Nixos ssh with ZSH - command not found

Tags: nixos, nix

I've got a fresh nixos VM. I have a minor issue where the PATH does not seem to be set when running commands via ssh. For example:

`ssh chris@192.168.0.10 'whoami'` - 
Outputs:

```
with zsh:1: command not found: whoami.
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add:

```
programs.zsh.enable = true;
```

To the configuration.